# LEFT JOIN sparse table onto large table

Tags: join, left-join, netezza

I have two tables that look like this

```
Date         ID            Date         ID    Value
2017-01-01   1             2017-01-01   1     10.0
2017-01-01   2             2017-01-01   2     15.0
2017-01-01   3             2017-01-02   3     20.0
2017-01-01   4             2017-01-02   4     50.0
2017-01-02   1
2017-01-02   2
2017-01-02   3
2017-01-02   4
```

I want to join the in a way to get

```
Date         ID   Value
2017-01-01   1    10.0  
2017-01-01   2    15.0
2017-01-01   3    NULL
2017-01-01   4    NULL
2017-01-02   1    NULL
2017-01-02   2    NULL
2017-01-02   3    20.0
2017-01-02   4    50.0
```

I tried left joining T2 on T1 by using ID and Date which results always just in only the records that matched. If I only join on ID I get multiple entries (each Value) for each date.

```
SELECT
  t1.Date,
  t1.ID,
  t2.Value
FROM table1 t1
left join table2 t2 using (Date,ID)
```

Comment: I am using Netezza

Comment: You should add the statement you tried so far.

Comment: I'd guess you have a where clause that is filtering out the nulls from the left join.  Likely something limiting t2.  The SQL you have written looks like it should work w/o issue.

Comment: RexTester example showing it working: http://rextester.com/LGXHI32164  (though I admit I escaped date and value since they were key/reserved words.)  and by limiting t2 comment I mean `where t2.value >0`

Comment: After some try and error I have a feeling netezza is doing an inner join in that particular instance, if I use a with table1 as (), table2 as() structure you can do a left join in the final select statement and it will work, odd.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way of phrasing it:

```
SELECT
    t1.Date,
    t1.ID,
    t2.Value
FROM
    table1 t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2 ON
        t1.Date = t2.Date
        AND t1.ID = t2.ID
```